# How do I make a program immutable?

Tags: solana-program

Say I have a deployed Solana Program with an upgrade authority. What is the best practice to revoke this authority?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer in the [docs](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/bpf_loader_upgradeable/index.html#):

When deploying a program normally, I use

`solana program deploy`

which makes it upgradeable by default. If I want to make it non-upgradeable, I can deploy (an update) using:

`solana program deploy --final`

Comment: Don't forget to click ‘accept answer’ to mark your self-answer as the accepted one!

Comment: It only lets me do that after 2 days, but thanks for the reminder nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make an existing program immutable, it's easier to simply remove the upgrade authority, rather than going through another deployment:

```
solana program set-upgrade-authority <PROGRAM_ADDRESS> --final
```